# jQuery - fiter divs by content

Tags: jquery, input, filter

How can I filter divs by span content in jQuery? For exmple div with text onion inside should be displayed only if is checked Vegetable or Winter checkbox.

```
<div>
                <input type="checkbox" id="Fruit">
                <label for="Fruit">Fruit</label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" id="Vegetable">
                <label for="Vegetable">Vegetable</label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" id="Summer">
                <label for="Summer">Summer</label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" id="Winter">
                <label for="Winter">Winter</label>
            </div>

<div class="results">
  <div>
       <h1>Onion</h1>
       <span>Vegetable</span>
       <span>Winter</span>
  </div>

  <div>
       <h1>Banana</h1>
       <span>Fruit</span>
       <span>Summer</span>
  </div>

   <div>
       <h1>Rock</h1>
       <span>Fruit</span>
  </div>

     <div>
       <h1>Orange</h1>
       <span>Summer</span>
  </div>

</div>
```

whole code is [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qOYqwv)

Comment: Put all relevant code in the question itself. That link can change and questions should be self contained. We shouldn't have to go off site to see your code. Demos are great for testing but show your attempts to solve this in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the :contains selector. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bVMgaY

```
$("input:checkbox").on('click', function(event){
  $("div.results").children().hide();
  $("input:checked").each(function(){
     $("span:contains('" + $(this).prop('id') + "')", 'div.results').parent('div').show();
  });
});
```

Comment: Nice, but I want to checkboxes - if its everything unchecked, all divs must be displayed.

Comment: updated. You just need another loop to apply all checked boxes

Comment: Wow, exactly what I need. But why rest of divs dont appear again If I uncheck checkbox?

Comment: Because you asked to filter by the content. if nothing is selected there is nothing to show